# how do I create an array populated by class instances in swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, for-loop, ios7, swift

Hi all I am trying to create an array which is populated with some instances of my class BlogPost

I've started off with this :-

```
{
var blog : [BlogPost] = []

for item in blog{
}
```

am I on the right track here? just want to create 10 of these instances using a for loop
any help appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the another way to do that:

```
var blog : [BlogPost] = []
for i in 1...10 {

    blog.append(i)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

10 posts in a blog

```
var blog = (1...10).map { _ in BlogPost() }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in blog{
}
```

won't do anything since your array is empty. Simply, iterate n(n being the number of posts you'd like to create) times, each time creating a new object and adding it to the array;

```
let n : Int = 10
for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
    arr.append(BlogPost())
}
```

Comment: thanks ok so create an index then append it to the blog post. What is arr?